# Highly irregular beaming in this Liszt piece - is phrasal beaming a no-no or not?

Tags: piano, notation, beaming, phrase

The piece is Liszt's Heroischer Marsch im Ungarischem Stil, S.231, and the passage is this (measures 57-64). Notice how irregular the beaming is in the right hand, going across barlines and grouping together some notes whilst leaving others stranded.

[image: passage with irregular beaming]

At least [three versions of the sheet music](https://imslp.org/wiki/Heroischer_Marsch_in_ungarischem_Stil,_S.231_(Liszt,_Franz)) use this same beaming.

Note that all of the 16th notes have the same duration; none of them are hidden triplets (like in ms 55). I am having a hard time interpreting what this signifies. My only explanation is that it is meant to show phrasing; that you should really feel and express the melody as groups of 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, and 15 notes whilst playing the melody.

But [several sources](https://ravenmusic.org/music-notation-guide) call beaming for phrases a ["common error"](https://blogs.iu.edu/jsomcomposition/music-notation-style-guide/), or establish [really strict beaming rules](https://www.scoringnotes.com/tips/djas-notes-music-preparation-basics/), all in the name of readability. So well, why'd Liszt do it?

Is this phrasal beaming:

- a highly unusual thing for Liszt to do ([as we know him for](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/108119/why-are-there-fingerings-in-liszts-beethovens-9th-transcription-a-piece-for-a)).
- something common in Liszt's time that's discredited now.
- something that, as far as the method works go, young music students need to be discouraged from doing as they are likely to go nuts with it; whilst only experts know how to properly use phrasal beaming.
- not at all phrasal beaming but something else.

Comment: It’s an ‘error’ only if there’s no reason for it, and where phrase marks would be clearer. Strangely, your source gives a perfect example of when it’s useful, despite complaining that it’s ‘unclear’... their ‘clear’ version is pedantically correct but not so easily readable to me. Try some more mainstream sources like Read or Gould.

Answer (score 2):

Phrasal beaming is frowned upon nowadays, particularly in ensemble music, but it's still very common in solo music. Obviously Liszt was trying to convey the phrasing, but it does make the music much harder to read. This last aspect is less important in a solo piece which is unlikely to be sight read.

Comment: *Phrasal beaming is frowned upon nowadays, particularly in ensemble music, but it's still very common in solo music.* Your sentence reads a little ambiguously to me. Is it frowned upon in solo music, or not?

Comment: Adding phrasing marks to all that ink usage wouldn't really make it any easier to read and learn to play properly. What would be the advantage to a player? +1.

Comment: @KeizerHarm It's not considered quite as bad when used in solo music. But composers often don't care about the rules.

Comment: frowned upon by who? Just interested

Comment: @DamianleGassick The sources referenced by OP among others

Comment: yes, but the sources quoted by the OP are simple guides for beginners - not really relevant to the Liszt in question. Liszt, Brahms, Rachmaninov, Stravinsky... they’re all fine with it if the notation suggests something that phrasing/articulation don’t on their own. I do agree with the OP that it isn’t clear what Liszt’s notation actually adds here.

Comment: @DamianleGassick A couple of those are music preparation guides for professionals. Also from Elaine Gould's standard work on notation "Behind Bars": "Changing beaming in this way should be used with great care: when the performer is forced to think across the beat it is all too easy to lose count."

Comment: I only see guides for students in the links. Gould, agreed, is the modern go to. ‘Used with care’ is not the same as ‘frowned upon’